# probability of the limsup of a sequence of events

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be jointly defined random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. Suppose for all $n$ we have 
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty i^2P(i\leq X_n<i+1)<C<\infty$$
for some fixed $C>0$. Show that
$$P(\limsup_n\{\omega\in\Omega: X_n(\omega)\geq n\})=0$$

Here is what I thought: Let 
$$A_n:=\{\omega\in\Omega: X_n(\omega)\geq n\}$$ and let 
$$B_{n,i}=\{\omega\in\Omega: i\leq X_n(\omega)<i+1\})$$

Then $A_n$ can be written as the disjoint union
$$A_n=\bigcup_{i\geq n}B_{n,i}$$

What I want to prove is 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n)<\infty$$
thus by Borel-Catelli lemma we have $P(\limsup_{n} A_n)=0$. I am have difficulty to prove this and I am even not sure if I am on the right track. Can anyone help with this? Thank a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Observe that

$$\begin{aligned}&P(A_n)=\sum_{i=n}^\infty P(B_{n,i})=\sum_{i=n}^\infty P(i\leq X_n<i+1)\\
\leq& \sum_{i=n}^\infty\frac{i^2}{n^2}P(i\leq X_n<i+1)=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=n}^\infty i^2P(i\leq X_n<i+1)\\
\leq&\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^\infty i^2P(i\leq X_n<i+1)\leq\frac{C}{n^2}\end{aligned}$$

Thus the result follows